# How to show the values of a single dataframe from the merge between two dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am newbie in python, I have one scenario :
I have two dataframes df_open & df_closed. df_open is having old values and needs to be updated using df_closed periodically.
For ex:
df_open

| Primary_key | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

df_closed

| Primary_key | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | X |
| 3 | C |

And my desired output is
df_open

| Primary_key | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | X |
| 3 | C |

This is some kinda of upsert operation which needs to be implemented using python pandas.
Thanks :)

Comment: With this example, I am not completely understanding, partly because your expected output of df_open is a copy of df_close, in this demo, but you can try `df_open = df_close.combine_first(df_open)`

Comment: Sorry for confusing, actually df_open should be a master file and I receive df_closed everyday. So sometimes df_close will be having very few records (Primary_key) which should be updated in df_open. Lets assume tomorrow I will receive df_closed with only 1 record Primary_key : 1 , Name : Y >> This should be updated in df_open. Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet to verify first. For your example though, I think right join will do the job.

`df_open.merge(df_closed, on=('Primary_key', 'Name'), how='right')`